# what am i doing wrong? cant seem to pass a parameter to server

Tags: python, bottle

I am trying to have user enter a number which will call a query and show the results in a table for user to compare, but when the user submits the form, the python program gets the input and get the results properly.

In short, user enters a number and it generates a small table of results.

Some reason the input is not been passed.

Please check my work to see what is wrong.

Here is main.py:

```
from bottle import request, route, run, view

@route('/')
@view('index.html')
def index():
    print request.GET.get('choice');
    return dict(choice = request.method == 'GET');

run(host = 'localhost', port = 9988);
```

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search Engine Comparator!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #navlist li
            {
                display: inline;
                list-style-type: none;
                padding-right: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
        % from bSearch import *
        % from gSearch import *     
        % from termList import *        
        <center><h2>Search Engine Comparator</h2></center>  
        <div id="navcontainer" align="center">
            <ul id="navlist">
                <ul>
                    % r1 = getList1();
                    % for r in r1:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    % r2 = getList2();
                    % for r in r2:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    % r3 = getList3();
                    % for r in r3:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    % r4 = getList4();
                    % for r in r4:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    % r5 = getList5();
                    % for r in r5:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
            </ul>
            <ul id="navlist">
                <ul>
                    % r6 = getList6();
                    % for r in r6:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    % r7 = getList7();
                    % for r in r7:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    % r8 = getList8();
                    % for r in r8:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    % r9 = getList9();
                    % for r in r9:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    % r10 = getList10();
                    % for r in r10:
                    <li> {{ r }} </li>
                    % end
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        % choice = request.GET.get('choice');
        % if choice:
        <form action="/" method="get" id="resForm" name="resForm">
            <div align="center">
                <label for="choice">Enter which list to query:</label>
                <input type="text" name="choice" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>          
        % else:
        <form action="" method="get" id="resForm" name="resForm">
            <div align="center">
                <label for="choice">Enter which list to query:</label>
                <input type="text" name="choice" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>              
            % queries = getQueries(choice);
            % for q in queries:
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th></th><th>The query is: {{ q }}</th><th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="b" name="bing">I pick this!!!</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="g" name="goog">I pick this!!!</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="y" name="yhoo">I pick this!!!</td>                
                </tr>               
                <tr>                    
                    <td width="33%">
                        <ol>
                            % bRes = bSearch(q);        
                            % for b in bRes[:8]:
                            <li>{{ b.title }} <br /> <a href={{ b.url }}>{{ b.url }}</a></li>
                            % end
                        </ol>
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%">
                        <ol>

                        </ol>
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%">
                        <ol>
                            <li>aint working b!</li>
                        </ol>
                    </td>                   
                </tr>   
                <br />
                % end       
            </table>            
            % end
            <center><br /><input type="button" id="checker" value="Click to get the count!" onclick="checkerCount()" /></center>
        </form>     
    </body>
</html>     

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkerCount() 
{
    var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var size = inputTags.length;
    var b = 0;
    var g = 0;
    var y = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        if(inputTags[i].type=='checkbox' && inputTags[i].checked && inputTags[i].id=='b') { b++; }
        if(inputTags[i].type=='checkbox' && inputTags[i].checked && inputTags[i].id=='g') { g++; }
        if(inputTags[i].type=='checkbox' && inputTags[i].checked && inputTags[i].id=='y') { y++; }
    }
    alert("After counting and all that, we found the scores!\n" + 
          "Bing has score: " + b +
          "\nGoogle has score: " + g + 
          "\nYahoo has score: " + y);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code from the template to the `index()` function and pass the lists as dictionary values.

In general, try to restrict the programming logic in a template to a minimum required to render data.

Comment: can you please explain that in dumb people terms.. so basically move all "% python code" to index()?

Comment: @Joe Chen: yes. You understand this right. It is not your immediate problem but if you move the code it should solve itself too. The fact that the template language allows an arbitrary Python code doesn't mean that it is a good idea to put it there. btw, you don't need to put *literally* all the code inside a single `index()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what this line is supposed to be doing:

```
return dict(choice = request.method == 'GET');
```

This is creating a dictionary with a single key, 'choice', whose value is either `True` if the request method is GET, or `False` otherwise. I highly doubt that's what you meant. Perhaps you meant this:

```
return {'choice': request.GET.get('choice')}
```

Comment: i got that from online somewhere, i was thinking to return the choice so the html page would know which function to call..

Comment: Fine, but your code isn't returning the choice. It's returning a boolean of whether the request method was GET.

Comment: @JoeChen: you might mean the code from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9541298/4279) where `index()` serves both GET and POST requests. I've done it to make the example concise (I should've made it clear that it is *not* an invitation to put arbitrary Python code into the template). In your case  `index()` serves only GET requests so `request.method` is always `'GET'`. Returning `dict(key=123)` from the `index()` means that you could use `{{ key }}` to insert `123` in the template (`index.html`).